# How to create new field in view with some offset (field of table) from existing field (another field of table)?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-view

I have table `Contracts`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Contracts` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `supplier_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `shop_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `conclusionDate` DATE NOT NULL,
    `period` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Contracts_Shop` FOREIGN KEY (`shop_id`) REFERENCES `shop` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Contracts_Suppliers` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_id`) REFERENCES `suppliers` (`id`)
)
```

I want to create something like this:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    s.name as supplierName,
    c.conclusionDate, 
    c.conclusionDate+year(c.period) as cancelDate, 
    c.period
FROM
    Contracts as c
INNER JOIN
    Suppliers as s
ON 
    s.id = c.supplier_id
```

It is code of my view at the moment. As result I want rows in which cancel date is date with offset in years (`period` field — int type) from conclusion date (`conclusionDate` field — date type).

Yesterday, I saw such example, but I can't find it now :( Help me please.

Expected results:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + supplierName + conclusionDate + cancelDate + period +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  + bob1         + 2014-05-05     + 2015-05-05 + 1      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 2  + bob2         + 2014-01-01     + 2018-05-05 + 4      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 3  + bob3         + 2012-08-03     + 2017-08-03 + 5      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Show some sample dataset together with expected resultset

Comment: I added example of exepcted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by just adding your period column using `interval` with your conclusionDate

```
c.conclusionDate + interval c.period year as cancelDate
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0f47/3)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
ADDDATE(c.conclusionDate, INTERVAL c.period YEAR) as cancelDate,
```

Comment: I am getting [this](http://i.gyazo.com/77357e783984b37022bc79ef3a4af5b1.png). SQL code is [here](https://gist.github.com/sharikovvladislav/75d4d326829de592eb72).